# Hangman repeated instance of letters fix?

Tags: python

I have been working on a little hangman game for python. For words like Laptop, I have two p's so it only recognizes the first p and doesn't go on to add the second p, how do I fix this?

This is my code so far.

```
import random



def hangman_play():
    list_words = ['computer', 'television', 'laptop', 'phone', 'dracula']

    random_num = random.randint(0, len(list_words))
    random_word = list_words[random_num]
    random_word = list(random_word)
    print(random_word)
    user_guessed_choices = []
    for i in range(0, len(random_word)):
        user_guessed_choices.append('-')
    print(user_guessed_choices)
    tries_left = len(user_guessed_choices)
    chances = 8

    while chances != 0:

            user = input(f'Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have {chances} tries ')
            if user_guessed_choices == random_word:
                print('You win!')
                break
            elif user.lower() in random_word:
                user_guessed_choices[random_word.index(user)] = user
                print(f'{user} is correct! Added to the word')
                print(user_guessed_choices)
            elif user.lower() in user_guessed_choices:
                print('Hey! You used that letter already!')
                chances = chances - 1
                print(f'You have ({tries_left}) left')
            elif user.lower() not in random_word:
                print('Thats incorrect!')
                chances = chances - 1
                print(f'You have {chances} left')
            elif chances==0:
                print('You ran out of chances! You lose!')


hangman_play()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that random_word.index(user) just gives you the first index that fits.

You have two options:

1. You could 'manually' run through the word till the end and do a replacement in the user_guessed_choices whenever you find the letter. This would look something like this:

```
for idx, l in enumerate(random_word):
   if l == user:
      user_guessed_choices[idx] = user
```

2. You use a regular expression and look for all the indices, that contain the letter. This, however, bears a lot more overhead than the first solution. But if you are interested, this would look something like this:

```
import re
...
indices = [x.span()[0] for x in re.compile(user).finditer(random_word)]
if indices:
   for index in indices:
      user_guessed_choices[index] = user
```

(This would just require, that you store your word as a string, not a list as you have it currently)

I would definitely recommend going for the first solution as it is probably much faster and less confusing.

Comment: could you please clarify what that l==user: is doing?

Comment: @Jos Yeah, of course. There I run through each letter of the random_word and store it in the variable `l` and compare this variable `l` with the input the user gave, which is stored in the variable `user`. If the two values are equal, I store the user-input in the user_guessed_choices. To know, at which place in the user_guessed_choices I have to place it, I use the `enumerate`-function, which also gives me the index for each letter in the `random_word`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I forget to use these useful functions sometimes
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's because `list.index(x)` just return the first occurrence of `x`, so you need a loop to check and change all the letters. Besides, you have several problems in your code:

1. Creating `random_word` may raise `IndexError`. `randint(a, b)` will return an integer from `a` to `b` with `b` included, so `random_num` may equal to `len(list_words)`. Use `randrange(a, b)` if you want to exclude `b` or just use `random.choice` to select an item.
2. `elif user.lower() in user_guessed_choices:` will not run. When the letter is repeated, it is also a correct letter which will run `if user.lower() in random_word:`. Move the repeat letter check before the correct letter check. Also, you use `tries_left` here while others are `chances`.
3. You need to input one more time before win. When you guess the last correct letter, it is appended in the user guess, and this user guess is checked in next loop. Check if the user win when you get a correct letter.

Here's the code after change:

```
import random

def hangman_play():
    list_words = ['computer', 'television', 'laptop', 'phone', 'dracula']

    random_word = list(random.choice(list_words))
    user_guessed_choices = ['-' for i in range(len(random_word))]

    chances = 8
    print(user_guessed_choices)

    while chances != 0:
        user = input(f'Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have {chances} tries ').lower()

        if user in user_guessed_choices:
            print('Hey! You used that letter already!')
            chances = chances - 1
        elif user in random_word:
            for idx, letter in enumerate(random_word):
                if user == letter:
                    user_guessed_choices[idx] = letter
            
            print(f'{user} is correct! Added to the word')
            print(user_guessed_choices)
            if user_guessed_choices == random_word:
                print('You win!')
                break
        else:
            print('Thats incorrect!')
            chances = chances - 1
    else:
        print('You ran out of chances! You lose!')

hangman_play()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone uses the hangman game as a way to learn about lists and indexes, but we can also use it to teach about numpy's powerful **masking** feature.

If we use numpy arrays of characters instead of lists of characters, we get rid of the `index` method, we get rid of manual loops to work around the weakness of `index`:

```
mask = random_word == user_input # Locations of the letter that was just guessed correctly.
user_guessed_choices[mask] = random_word[mask]
```

The first line will give us a boolean array. If the random word is "dracula" and the guess is "a", the mask will look like `[False, False, True, False, False, False, True]`. We then shove the guessed character in `user_guessed_choices` everywhere the mask is true, which is very nice. `user_guessed_choices` goes from `["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]` to `["-", "-", "a", "-", "-", "-", "a"]`.

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np

def hangman_play():

    list_words = ['computer', 'television', 'laptop', 'phone', 'dracula']
    random_word = np.array(list(np.random.choice(list_words)))
    user_guessed_choices = np.full_like(random_word, "-")
    chances = len(random_word) + 4 # Give a few more tries than there are letters.

    while chances != 0:

        # Check for victory condition *before* asking for a new letter guess.
        if (user_guessed_choices == random_word).all():
            print('You win!')
            break

        # Other cases.
        user_input = input(f'Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have {chances} tries left. ').lower()

        if user_input in random_word:
            mask = random_word == user_input # Locations of the letter that was just guessed correctly.
            user_guessed_choices[mask] = random_word[mask]
            print(f'{user_input.upper()} is correct! Added to the word.')
            print("".join(user_guessed_choices).upper())

        elif user_input in user_guessed_choices:
            print('Hey! You used that letter already!')

        elif user_input not in random_word:
            print("That's incorrect!")

        elif chances == 0:
            print('You ran out of chances! You lose!')

        chances -= 1

hangman_play()
```

Example game:

```
Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have 11 tries left. A
A is correct! Added to the word.
--A---A

Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have 10 tries left. U
U is correct! Added to the word.
--A-U-A

Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have 9 tries left. D
D is correct! Added to the word.
D-A-U-A

Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have 8 tries left. R
R is correct! Added to the word.
DRA-U-A

Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have 7 tries left. C
C is correct! Added to the word.
DRACU-A

Guess the word! Choose a letter, you have 6 tries left. L
L is correct! Added to the word.
DRACULA
You win!
```

Comment: thats such a great way of doing things, I use numpy just for datasets and never thought Id see it in something simple as hangman thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution to hangman when I used to do python courses with kids is to use sets.

You construct a set of guessed letters and cast the word to a set too. A set data structure automatically condenses duplicates. It's a list of only unique elements. The intersection of the two sets are the letters both that were guessed and that are in the word.

You can then loop over the characters in the word. If that character is in the intersection of the two sets, it was guessed. This works for every character so you don't have to worry about counting duplicates.

The intersection of 2 sets is strictly the elements which appear in both sets.

This is an example I wrote when I used to teach python. It's a bit longer than it needs to be just because it was meant to very explicitly show the concept. You'd also need to modify it to fit into your turn system.

```
word = "firetech"

incomplete_set_of_guesses = ["i", "e", "h", "x", "y"]

full_list_of_guesses = ["r", "e", "i", "f", "t", "h", "c", "x", "y"]


# a set is a data structure like a list but which has no duplicates, not any sense of order
word_as_a_set = set(word)
print(word)
print(word_as_a_set)
# the order may change from run to run

incomplete_set_of_guesses = set(incomplete_set_of_guesses)
full_set_of_guesses = set(full_list_of_guesses)

correctly_guessed = word_as_a_set.intersection(incomplete_set_of_guesses)
print(correctly_guessed)

# to prove it works for duplicates and incomplete guesses

revealed_word = ""

for character in word:
    if character in correctly_guessed:
        revealed_word += character
    else:
        revealed_word += "_"

print(revealed_word)

# and to prove it works for when you have guessed al the letters plus some extra

correctly_guessed = word_as_a_set.intersection(full_set_of_guesses)
print(correctly_guessed)
revealed_word = ""

for character in word:
    if character in correctly_guessed:
        revealed_word += character
    else:
        revealed_word += "_"

print(revealed_word)
```

I find I refer to this diagram a lot when using them. [image]

More on sets here if you're interested: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/07/an-intuitive-and-easy-guide-to-python-set-must-for-becoming-data-science-professional/